# Where did my improvement request go?

Tags: discussion, support, documentation

A week or two ago, I posted an improvement request in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/3114/stream/10614/using-streams). At one point, someone [suggested an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/79503) that would have handled the request. That edit was rejected, but now the improvement request is gone. What happened to the request? I can't find any accepted edits to that page since I last touched it, which was before the request was posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anyone can dimiss any improvement request without giving any reasons anytime they want with no logging of this event whatsoever. Improvement requests can disappear when moving examples, or if sombody edits an example and doesn't notice there were improvement requests, or there were added other improvement requests which were handled, but with your request checked by default as well...

Overall, improvement requests can disappear anytime and you can't do anything about it. Thank you for your time spent on adding improvement requests.

Comment: That's pretty surprising! I would've at least expected it to show up in the edit history or to have notified me. Good to know.

Comment: This may be what the system does but it seems a terrible way of doing things. It also contradicts the [documentation tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour/documentation) which states *"Anyone can contribute - All changes are reviewed by other users, and the full history is available to everyone, so you won't break anything."* My improvement request appears to have vanished, so someone else broke it and I have not been informed.